# Change UDP port with iptables for VPN clients

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

**What I want to do is say that for all UDP connections on interface ppp0 that have a destination port of 53, change that destination port to 1053.**

I am attempting to change the destination port of UDP packets for VPN clients connected via PPTP on Ubuntu.

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242772/using-iptables-to-change-a-destination-port
suggests that this can be done using NAT at the --to-destination option, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:1053
```

This does work but it changes the port for ALL packets going out on port 53 but I only want to chane the port for some of my VPN clients who are connected on interface ppp0-255 and IP range 192.168.0.10-255.

I have tried adding the source into the statement, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.10 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:1053
```

This however does not appear to work and the VPN connections still go through to port 53.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have IP forwarding enabled at the VPN Server?

Comment: yes, IP forwarding is enabled.. the VPN client can route through the VPN without any problems. What I want to do is for some users change their DNS server so in ip-up add a firewall command that changes the port of the DNS server to a different server listening on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ppp+ -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1053`

I have not tried it but it should work.

Good luck!

Comment: This seems to do something but I'm not sure what. On the face of it things should work as expected but my VPN traffic simply looses the ability to connect to the DNS even though it is listening on 1053.

Comment: oops, enter submit! It's almost as if the ports are wrong but if I use nslookup and set the port to 1053 I can resolve as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thats strange. What does `iptables -L` show?

Comment: So you have two dns servers running i assume: one on port 53 for the normal usage and one on port 1053 for the pptp clients?